# How to create fields automaticlly in Java without Adobe Acrobat

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have to fill pdf fields.
What I have done so far is to open my pdf like a form with Adobe Acrobat and then save it. It turns into a pdf forms and with Apache PdfBox I can achieve what I want to do.
Unfortunately, I must not open it with an external program. And if I don't do this little trick, I have an empty array with :

```
DDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(new File(path));
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDoc.getDocumentCatalog();                                 
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm(); 
acroForm.getFields() //empty
```

Is it possible to create dynamicly in java my future fields from a simple pdf?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Add the pdf here so we can have a look

Comment: There is no *automatic* recognition of drawn form fields in pdfbox. You can use it to define corn fields by coordinates, though.